# Plotting over groups of values in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn, python-ggplot

I have a dataframe that looks like this.

```
        country  age  new_user  
298408      UK   32         1   
193010      US   37         0 
164494      UK   17         0   
28149       US   34         0  
297080   China   29         1
```

I want to plot the count of new_users for the age groups (20-30, 30-40 and so on) for each country in a single graph in Python.

Basically, I need to plot new_user(value 0) for all the age groups and new_user(value 1) for all the age groups for all the countries.

I am finding it hard to group the ages into 20-30,30-40 and so on. 
Can someone please help me plot this using either seaborn or ggplot or matplotlib in python? ggplot is preferrable!

Thank you.

Comment: you gonna have to `groupby` them to get the dataset with the actual values. Have you got that?

Comment: Histogram, with the obvious bin sizes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import seaborn as sns
from pandas import DataFrame
from matplotlib.pyplot import show, legend
d = {"country": ['UK','US','US','UK','PRC'],
       "age": [32, 37, 17, 34, 29],
       "new_user": [1, 0, 0, 0,1]}

df = DataFrame(d)
bins = range(0, 100, 10)
ax = sns.distplot(df.age[df.new_user==1],
              color='red', kde=False, bins=bins, label='New')
sns.distplot(df.age[df.new_user==0],
         ax=ax,  # Overplots on first plot
         color='blue', kde=False, bins=bins, label='Existing')
legend()
show()
```

[image]